Why does 受信箱 have a downstep when both 受信 and 箱 are heiban?
Keeping in mind that yes, pitch accent is sometimes quite arbitrary, I'm wondering if there's a tendency which explains why 受信 is heiban, 箱 is heiban, but compounds such as:

受信料
受信箱

consistently have the pitch accent [じゅしん]{HHHL}.
I know that there's tendencies where certain X+Y compounds will receive a downstep after the first mora of Y, but this doesn't appear to be the case here, since the downstep appears on the first element of the compound.

The pronunciation of "Hako" and "Bako" normally is different isn't it? So, the compound can be different at times like this example.

I think I say じゅ[しんばこ]{HHLL}.

Some suffixes bring up the tail of the preceding word and start low itself. It could be just that ん tends to drop early. I have a feeling the same thing happens with 長音. I'm not certain enough to write an answer.
